# KDB/Q: Given a matrix, return only the rows where every element in the row is greater than 5

Tags: matrix, kdb

Given a matrix/list of lists 
M:(1 9 10;120 50 199;15 20 7)
Return only the rows where every element in the row is greater than 5.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick for you:

```
q)M where all each M>5
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use

```
M where 5<min flip M
```

Or a slight alternative to Seans

```
M where all flip M>5
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also find this usefull as well:

```
q){if[all x<M y;:M y]}[8]'[til count M]
```

Even though the previous solutions seem to be slightly more efficient, a function is always useful.